# Divergence an iterated series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ are two infinite sequences of non negative numbers. Suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j$ diverges. Then is it true that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j$  also diverges? I think this is true, but how to prove it?

Comment: If $a_i$ and $b_j$ are nonnegative, the two things $\sum_i \sum_j a_i b_j$ and $\sum_j \sum_i a_i b_j$ are equal (so yes).

Comment: why are the two series the same? Could the sum not be different depending on in what order we do the sum?

Comment: @user286813 the sums could be different. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Answer (score 0):

This way uses measure theory:

Let $\mu$ the counting measure in $\mathbb{N}$ and define $f:\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(i,j)=a_ib_j$. Since $f$ is nonnegative, the Tonelli-Fubbini theorem gives
$$\int\int f(x,y)d\mu(x)d\mu(y)=\int\int f(x,y)d\mu(y)d\mu(x)\quad\quad (1)$$
even when a integral is not finite. Note: $\int\int f(x,y)d\mu(x)d\mu(y)=\sum_j\sum_if(i,j)$.

This also extend the result for nonnegative $f$. If a integral in (1) is finite for $|f|$, then $f$ is integrable and (1) holds as well for $f$. This means that if $\sum_j\sum_i|f(i,j)|<\infty$ or $\sum_i\sum_j|f(i,j)|<\infty$, then $\sum_i\sum_jf(i,j)=\sum_j\sum_if(i,j)$ and, particulary, the sums actually converge.

Answer (score 0):

Factoring out, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_ib_j\right) =\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j \right).$$ If $\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j$ diverges, the sum diverges. If it converges to $B$ the expression becomes $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i B = B\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$$ which diverges if and only if $\sum_i a_i$ converges. So the sum diverges if and only if $\sum_i a_i$ or $\sum_j b_j$ diverge.

An identical  argument shows that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ib_j\right)$$ diverges if and only if $\sum_i a_i$ or $\sum_j b_j$ diverge.

This does not require that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are non-negative and also applies to the double infinite sum $\lim_{M,N\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=1}^N a_i b_j.$ In the more genaral case $\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}$ where $c_{ij}$ does not factor into $a_ib_j$, the above argument does not work and it's not true in general, but it does suffice (by Fubini-Tonelli or otherwise) that $c_{ij}\ge 0$ for the double sum and both iterated sums to be identical.